# C++ The value of my input variable changes by itself?

Tags: c++

```cpp
int main() {
    int m;
    cin >> m;
    int len = 0;
    if (m <= 1) {
        cout << m << endl;
        return 0;
    } else {
        int a[] = {
            0,
            1
        };
        for (int i = 2; i <= m * m; ++i) {
            cout << "second" << m << " " << m * m << endl;
            a[i] = (a[i - 2] + a[i - 1]) % m;
            cout << m << " " << m * m << endl;
            if (a[i] == 1 && a[i - 1] == 0) {
                len = i - 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << len << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
2
second2 4
1 1
0
```

I'm storing the input into the variable m(Input value is 2 in the example). However, after the statement `a[i] = (a[i-2]+a[i-1])%m;`, the value of m becomes 1. There's no decrement or anything happening, what would cause this to happen?

Comment: What causes it is the fact that your array has size two, but you are treating it as if it was much bigger.

Comment: How do you know that the value of m becomes 1? The value of m remains constant -> http://cpp.sh/7ep3li

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array `a` has only 2 elements, so writing (and reading) to `a[2]` and above is not allowed.

You should use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) to dynamically add elements to arrays.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main() {
    int m;
    cin>>m;
    int len=0;
    if(m<=1) {
        cout<<m<<endl;
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        std::vector<int> a={0,1}; // initializer list, which is supported in C++11 and later
        for(int i=2; i <= m*m; ++i) {
            cout<<"second"<<m<<" "<<m*m<<endl;
            a.push_back((a[i-2]+a[i-1])%m); // use push_back to add elements
            cout<<m<<" "<<m*m<<endl;
            if(a[i]==1 && a[i-1]==0) {
                len=i-1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<len<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That worked! I should have seen that. However, I don't get how that would affect the value of m though.

Comment: Apart from the obvious mistake OP's done (which is the actual issue, as you pointed out), the "error" OP's facing - the value of m changes - cannot be reproduced (and should not be reproducible in the first place). I am marking this as non-reproducible because I am not getting the same output as OP's

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 *Undefined behavior* is invoked by accessing out-of-range. The behavior need not be the same in all environments.

Comment: Yes, but won't that behaviour "affect" only the variables which are invoking undefined behaviour? How can 'm', an initialised variable, completely decoupled from the array be affected?

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 No. UB means what it says, it's *undefined behavior*. Absolutely anything in your program could go wrong.